# How do I force/configure Axis2 to use TLS 1.1 or later

Tags: java, java-7, apache-axis, tls1.2

I have an app connecting to a service using Axis2-generated sources (WSDL2java client code, XMLbeans, using axis2-1.6.4). It has been working great.

The service I am connecting to is going to stop accepting incoming TLSv1 connections soon, so I need to figure out how to connect using TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. My client code is running java 1.7, and I've confirmed that the necessary support is there by creating a simple test client and running it like this

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 TestConnect
```

After finally figuring out [how to pass that flag to my (grails) site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214754/setting-java-system-property-to-enable-tls1-1-for-older-grails-site-grails-2) which is the client in this case, it still doesn't seem to be affecting the handshake at all. Meaning, the socket is reset when it tries to connect (unlike my TestConnect app, which connects just fine). Also when I also set "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose" I see that v1.0 is still being used in the handshake:

```
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
http-bio-8080-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
http-bio-8080-exec-9, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
http-bio-8080-exec-9
, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  
fatal, 
description = unexpected_message
http-bio-8080-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8080-exec-9, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

I also finally noticed that -- based on the docs [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https) -- setting https.protocol will only affect connections made through use of the HttpsURLConnection class or via URL.openStream() operations. This makes me suspect axis2 is doing something else, or hopefully has a different way of enabling this same support.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Or confirm or disprove my thoughts?

Here's the full stacktrace(s):

```
2016-02-06 13:25:06,942 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2016-02-06 13:25:06,948 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Message: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    Line | Method
->>  430 | makeFault               in org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     78 | writeTo                 in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter
|     84 | writeRequest . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity
|    499 | writeRequestBody        in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
|   2114 | writeRequest . . . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
|   1096 | execute                 in     ''
|    398 | executeWithRetry . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
|    171 | executeMethod           in     ''
|    397 | executeMethod . . . . . in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
|    621 | executeMethod           in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender
|    193 | sendViaPost . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
|     75 | send                    in     ''
|    396 | writeMessageWithCommons in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
|    223 | invoke                  in     ''
|    443 | send . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine
|    406 | send                    in org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient
|    229 | executeImpl . . . . . . in     ''
|    165 | execute                 in org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient
|   1960 | login . . . . . . . . . in com.zuora.api.ZuoraServiceStub
|     51 | ___init___              in com.zuora.zortal.util.ZApi$$EPbyIuau
|     48 | <init> . . . . . . . .  in com.zuora.zortal.repository.ZuoraRepository
|     40 | login                   in saaseiportal.unauthorized.LoginController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by WstxIOException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
->>  261 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     50 | flush                   in org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper
|    224 | close . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter
|    320 | ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainer$serializeAndConsume in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport
|      1 | serializeAndConsume . . in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl
|     74 | writeTo                 in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter
|     84 | writeRequest . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity
|    499 | writeRequestBody        in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
|   2114 | writeRequest . . . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
|   1096 | execute                 in     ''
|    398 | executeWithRetry . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
|    171 | executeMethod           in     ''
|    397 | executeMethod . . . . . in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
|    621 | executeMethod           in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender
|    193 | sendViaPost . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
|     75 | send                    in     ''
|    396 | writeMessageWithCommons in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
|    223 | invoke                  in     ''
|    443 | send . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine
|    406 | send                    in org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient
|    229 | executeImpl . . . . . . in     ''
|    165 | execute                 in org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient
|   1960 | login . . . . . . . . . in com.zuora.api.ZuoraServiceStub
|     51 | ___init___              in com.zuora.zortal.util.ZApi$$EPbyIuau
|     48 | <init> . . . . . . . .  in com.zuora.zortal.repository.ZuoraRepository
|     40 | login                   in saaseiportal.unauthorized.LoginController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
->>   82 | flushBuffer             in java.io.BufferedOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    140 | flush                   in     ''
|    191 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream
|    103 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer
|    225 | flush . . . . . . . . . in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter
|    259 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter
|     50 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper
|    224 | close                   in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter
|    320 | ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainer$serializeAndConsume in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport
|      1 | serializeAndConsume     in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl
|     74 | writeTo . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter
|     84 | writeRequest            in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity
|    499 | writeRequestBody . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
|   2114 | writeRequest            in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
|   1096 | execute . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    398 | executeWithRetry        in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
|    171 | executeMethod . . . . . in     ''
|    397 | executeMethod           in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
|    621 | executeMethod . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender
|    193 | sendViaPost             in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
|     75 | send . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    396 | writeMessageWithCommons in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
|    223 | invoke . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    443 | send                    in org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine
|    406 | send . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient
|    229 | executeImpl             in     ''
|    165 | execute . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient
|   1960 | login                   in com.zuora.api.ZuoraServiceStub
|     51 | ___init___ . . . . . .  in com.zuora.zortal.util.ZApi$$EPbyIuau
|     48 | <init>                  in com.zuora.zortal.repository.ZuoraRepository
|     40 | login . . . . . . . . . in saaseiportal.unauthorized.LoginController
|    195 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker               in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                     in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
->>   82 | flushBuffer             in java.io.BufferedOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    140 | flush                   in     ''
|    191 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream
|    103 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer
|    225 | flush . . . . . . . . . in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter
|    259 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter
|     50 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper
|    232 | flush                   in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter
|    318 | ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainer$serializeAndConsume in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport
|      1 | serializeAndConsume     in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl
|     74 | writeTo . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter
|     84 | writeRequest            in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity
|    499 | writeRequestBody . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
|   2114 | writeRequest            in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
|   1096 | execute . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    398 | executeWithRetry        in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
|    171 | executeMethod . . . . . in     ''
|    397 | executeMethod           in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
|    621 | executeMethod . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender
|    193 | sendViaPost             in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
|     75 | send . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    396 | writeMessageWithCommons in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
|    223 | invoke . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    443 | send                    in org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine
|    406 | send . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient
|    229 | executeImpl             in     ''
|    165 | execute . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient
|   1960 | login                   in com.zuora.api.ZuoraServiceStub
|     51 | ___init___ . . . . . .  in com.zuora.zortal.util.ZApi$$EPbyIuau
|     48 | <init>                  in com.zuora.zortal.repository.ZuoraRepository
|     40 | login . . . . . . . . . in saaseiportal.unauthorized.LoginController
|    195 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker               in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                     in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SocketException: Connection reset
->>  196 | read                    in java.net.SocketInputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    122 | read                    in     ''
|     82 | flushBuffer . . . . . . in java.io.BufferedOutputStream
|    140 | flush                   in     ''
|    191 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream
|    103 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer
|    225 | flush . . . . . . . . . in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter
|    259 | flush                   in com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter
|     50 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper
|    232 | flush                   in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter
|    318 | ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainer$serializeAndConsume in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport
|      1 | serializeAndConsume     in org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl
|     74 | writeTo . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter
|     84 | writeRequest            in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity
|    499 | writeRequestBody . . .  in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod
|   2114 | writeRequest            in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
|   1096 | execute . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    398 | executeWithRetry        in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
|    171 | executeMethod . . . . . in     ''
|    397 | executeMethod           in org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
|    621 | executeMethod . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender
|    193 | sendViaPost             in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
|     75 | send . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    396 | writeMessageWithCommons in org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
|    223 | invoke . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    443 | send                    in org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine
|    406 | send . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient
|    229 | executeImpl             in     ''
|    165 | execute . . . . . . . . in org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient
|   1960 | login                   in com.zuora.api.ZuoraServiceStub
|     51 | ___init___ . . . . . .  in com.zuora.zortal.util.ZApi$$EPbyIuau
|     48 | <init>                  in com.zuora.zortal.repository.ZuoraRepository
|     40 | login . . . . . . . . . in saaseiportal.unauthorized.LoginController
|    195 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker               in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                     in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Well, I found a solution. I imported a custom SSLSocketFactory as suggested by [these docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html). If you're lazy (like me), I went looking for one that already does it, and found [this](https://gist.github.com/fkrauthan/ac8624466a4dee4fd02f). It needed a couple small changes (implement the apache SecureProtocolSocketFactory). Finally, *somewhere* in my application I called

Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", new TLSSocketFactory(), 443));

At some point, I should really just update my axis2 stuff to something newer...

Comment: are you by chance dealing with Zuora blocking TLS 1.0 too?

Comment: Your solution worked for me! "new Protocol" seems to be deprecated, but at this point I don't care.

Comment: Lol, yes! We totally let this one catch us off guard (I think they had an announcement last October, but I guess we thought enabling it would be no problem and forgot about it.) If I find some extra time, I'll sit down and see if upgrading axis2 to something much newer just solves it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem only happens with Java 7 as Java 8 uses TLSv1.2 by default [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html)

You need to create SSLSocketFactory, I have pushed a pull request into the Zuora SDK doing that [here](https://github.com/zuora/rest-java-client/commit/34facbe8cd7e4a1b61ed388d9f3d96c3858169fe)

```
String TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
try {
    if (Boolean.valueOf(((String) ZConfig.getInstance().getVal("ssl.verify.peer")).toLowerCase())) {
        socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(TLS_VERSION, null, null, null, null, null,
                SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    } else {
        socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(TLS_VERSION, null, null, null, null, new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        }, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    }
    // need both http and https
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory));
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! I found a similar answer in my comment, but fixing the Zuora SDK is another step better! Thanks!